# plunker console not working

Tags: java, console, plunker

I'm doing some javascript programming using plunker.

When I tried to test on console, all I get is a dark screen. There's isn't a blank console for me to work on. I'd just updated to my plunker to the newest version.

Any ideas on how can I correct it? Thanks

Comment: Hi there: attaching both the code & error message. Thanks!
    
    //Case 1: if everything's true, make everything false.
    if (completedTodos === totalTodos) {
      for (var i = 0; i < totalTodos; i++) {
        this.todos[i].completed === false;
       }
    //Case 2: Otherwise, make everything true.
     } else {
       for (var i = 0; i < totalTodos; i++) {
         !this.todos[i].completed === true;  
       }
     }
    this.displayTodos();
    }

Comment: Error messages:
Event tracked Multipane Hide Preview Toolbar undefined undefined
editor-1.20.1.js:2 URL visited /edit/ckq5XE9KovQCkUYHyTv5
editor-1.20.1.js:2 Event tracked Multipane Show Preview Toolbar undefined undefined
editor-1.20.1.js:2 URL visited /edit/ckq5XE9KovQCkUYHyTv5?p=preview
script.js:64 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Comment: Just realised that I wasn't very clear before. I now figured out how to get the console but having the same error message with code as I have for over a day now. Apologies for the lack of clarity earlier- it's my first time posting on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Could you now please try to [edit] your question and include the error in its body?

Comment: Hi- thanks for your reply and sorry for the delated response. I've worked it out! I really appreciate your time.